# Segmentation fault core dumped due to reference variable of type size_t

Tags: c++, reference, segmentation-fault, pass-by-reference, size-t

The code below is to perform merge sort. The vector gets sorted correctly. I have passed by reference variable num of type size_t. This variable has been initialised to zero before being passed as a reference. Accessing the variable in the specified position causes segmentation fault core dumped. However, accessing it in other parts of merge_sort function causes no errors and gives expected results.
Few attempts earlier the same line of code was causing no error but all of a sudden it has started causing segmentation fault core dumped.
I want to know why this is happening.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cstdlib>
#define N_LIM 5
#define NUM_LIM 5
using namespace std;
size_t naive(vector<int> &a)
{
    size_t i=0,j=0,l=a.size()-1,k=0;
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
        for(j=i+1;j<=l;j++)
            if(a[i]>a[j])
                k++;
    return k;
}
void merge_sort(vector<int> &a,size_t m,size_t n,size_t &num,vector<int> &temp)
{
    if(m<n)
    {
        size_t l=(m+n)/2,ans=0;
        merge_sort(a,m,l,num,temp);
        merge_sort(a,l+1,n,num,temp);
        size_t p=m,q=l+1,r=m;
        while(p<=l && q<=n)
        {
            if(a[p]<=a[q])
            {
                temp[r]=a[p];
                r++;
                p++;
            }
            else
            {
                temp[r]=a[q];
                r++;
                q++;
//num=num+l-p+1;    causes segmentation fault   num has been initialised to zero before 1st call to merge_sort
                ans+=l-p+1;
            }
        }
        while(p<=l)
        {
            temp[r]=a[p];
            p++;
            r++;
        }
        while(q<=n)
        {
            temp[r]=a[q];
            r++;
            q++;
        }
        for(size_t i=m;i<r;i++)
            a[i]=temp[i];
//  num=444;    num can be accessed here without any problem
    }
}
size_t inversion(vector<int> &a,bool f=0)
{
    size_t num=0;
    vector<int> temp(a.size());
    merge_sort(a,0,a.size()-1,num,temp);
    if(f==1)
    {
        for(size_t i=0;i<a.size();i++)
            cout<<a[i]<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return num;
}
int stress_test()
{
    int n=rand()%N_LIM;
    vector<int> a(n),b(n);
    for(size_t i=0;i<n;i++)
        a[i]=b[i]=rand()%NUM_LIM;
    size_t ans1=naive(a);
    size_t ans2=inversion(a);
    if(ans1==ans2)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        cout<<"Input :";
        for(size_t i=0;i<n;i++)
            cout<<" "<<b[i];
        cout<<endl<<"Output :";
        for(size_t i=0;i<n;i++)
            cout<<" "<<a[i];
        cout<<endl<<"Ans_Naive = "<<ans1<<"\t"<<"Ans = "<<ans2<<endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    size_t z=0;
    while(++z<1000)
    {
        if(stress_test()==1)
            break;
    }
    size_t n=0;
    cin>>n;
    vector<int> a(n);
    for(size_t i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>a[i];
    size_t k=inversion(a,1);
    cout<<k<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please make a [mre]. In particular, show the code that calls `merge_sort`.

Comment: How large is the vector `a`?  If it is of length `n`, you are overrunning it.  Try replacing `a[i]` with `a.at(i)` everywhere and see if the code still runs.

Comment: There is no way for arithmetic involving only `size_t` to crash or segfault, even through a reference except for division by zero. You must have Undefined Behavior somewhere else in your code. The cause of the problem is not related to where it is actually crashing.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Since `num` is passed as a reference, there is presumably a pointer to its location somewhere behind the scenes, and if that pointer is overwritten, you could easily get a segfault on that line.

Comment: @NateEldredge n is not more than 5 as of now and each number is also less than 5.

Comment: Careful saying stuff like, "Everything is perfect." and then discussing how the program segfaults. It attracts trolls.

Comment: Also, please show the call to `inversion`.

Comment: A [mre] for this problem would be a complete program that compiles, runs, and segfaults without any user intervention. Note that it might not always segfault on our computers due to differences in the configurations of our computers and build tools, but if we can see the entire chain of events, the odds of spotting the mistake go up.

Comment: sorry my  bad @user4581301

Comment: @NateEldredge But that cannot happen without something causing Undefined Behavior. It is not possible to overwrite the memory representation of a reference (assuming it has one) without also entering Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about, Mohammad. That was mostly me being a troll.

Comment: @MohammadShahwez: That's not what I mean.  But if for instance you do `vector<int> a(n);` and then call `merge_sort(a, m, n, ...)` then you have a bug, because the last accessible element of `a` is `a[n-1]` and your function will access `a[n]`.

Comment: @NateEldredge I have passed n as a.size()-1 in 1st call to merge_sort in inversion function hence I guess no error because of that.

Comment: Because you are using recursion, you have to be very careful to ensure that the inputs are short enough to avoid exhausting Automatic storage and causing what's commonly called a stack overflow. Once the stack overflows, the program can fail in innumerable and unpredictable ways.

Comment: @MohammadShahwez: That seems wrong, I think it should be `a.size()+1`.

Comment: Tip: In C++ use `const` and stay away from `#define`. You want the type safety `const` affords.